# undefined reference to libnuma

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, shared-libraries, numa

i'm trying to compile a simple test-program with libnuma (only numa_available is called) and i get a undefined reference error for this function.

At first, i used apt-get to install libnuma-dev and then simply used gcc -lnuma -o test test.c to compile the test program. 
This led to 'undefined reference of `numa_available`'. 
Then, I used dpkg -L libnuma-dev to make sure that the lib is actually installed (and just be sure I used strings  to check whether the interface has changed or something - I know, this method is crap, but there were some "numa_available" strings in the lib, so i thought is rather safe to assume that the interface has not changed)

Then i also tried -l:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.so and -L/usr/lib/x86..gnu, however this always led to the undefined reference error.

Finally, i tried to statically link it (simply gcc -lnuma .... test.c /usr/lib../libnuma.a) and fortunately it works now... 
However, can anyone tell me why it does not work dynamically linked?

best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your link command ("gcc -lnuma .... test.c /usr/lib../libnuma.a"), the most likely reason is that you need to move `-lnuma` to after `test.c`. [--as-needed flag](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/gnu-ld-as-needed.html) is enabled by default in modern distros and will not link in library unless it has been referred by preceeding objects.

Comment: @user1583166 This has only been enabled by default in recent distros (e.g. Ubuntu 16). There are lots of recent questions about similar problems.